# Golang get files for inode

Tags: file, unix, go, filesystems, inode

Is it possible with Golang to get a list of file paths based on an inode? In other words, how do I implement this function?

```
func PathsFromInode(inode uint64) (paths []string) {
...
}
```

Comment: as far as the os is concerned, inodes are indexed by filename, not the other way around. Some filesystems have methods to do this, but otherwise you just have to search for it.

Comment: If it's possible on your platform, it's almost certainly possible using go, but you'll probably have to resort to using cgo to make system calls.

Comment: @Adrian: System calls are handled by the syscall mechanism.

Comment: I see. Alright, thanks a lot, folks.